# Android: How to detect if an Activity goes into the background?

Tags: android

I need a way for my Activity to known that it's going into the background, and not when it's getting killed. I thought about hooking at onStop(), but onStop() is called for both cases. In other words, is there a way to tell if when my Activity is moving into the background and not getting killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the onPause() method? From the docs:

> Called as part of the activity
>   lifecycle when an activity is going
>   into the background, but has not (yet)
>   been killed.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for? Or, more importantly, what are you going to do if you detect it? By definition, `onPause()` is when you should be starting to pause your worker threads and save your data back to persistent storage. In `onDestroy()`, you can call `isFinishing()` to see if you're on your way out or just destroying and then recreating yourself because of something like an orientation change.